# Installing WWW::Curl on WIndows 7, running into "List form of pipe open not implemented"

Tags: perl, windows-7, curl, libcurl, activeperl

Trying to install WWW:Curl on Windows.  So far I've done all of the following as per this page:

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.15/README.Win32

I am in the process of modifying Makefile.PL, but when it tries to run cpp (I changed to gcc), I get the following error:

```
List form of pipe open not implemented at Makefile.PL
```

It happens on this line of code:

```
open(H_IN, "-|", "gcc", $curl_h   # where curl.h is the complete path to my curl.h file.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scalar expression form of pipe open?

```
open(H_IN, "-|", "gcc $curl_h");

open(H_IN, "|gcc $curl_h");
```

This is safe enough if `$curl_h` doesn't have any whitespace, quotation marks, or wildcards.