# Error when building WWW::Curl module (v4.15) in Strawberry Perl v5.16.3

Tags: windows, perl, curl

I'm trying to build / install the WWW::Curl module for strawberry perl.

I had to make some adjustments in Makefile.PL according to instructions in: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.15/README.Win32

and in here: [Installing WWW::Curl on WIndows 7, running into "List form of pipe open not implemented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398083/installing-wwwcurl-on-windows-7-running-into-list-form-of-pipe-open-not-impl)

When I execute **perl Makefile.PL**, at the command prompt, I get the following messages:

```
Found curl.h in d:\curldev\include\curl\curl.h
Building curlopt-constants.c for your libcurl version
Building Easy.pm constants for your libcurl version
Building Share.pm constants for your libcurl version
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcurl
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lcurldll
Writing Makefile for WWW::Curl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

After that, when I run **dmake** I get the following error message:

```
D:\perl\cpan\build\WWW-Curl>dmake
Skip blib\lib\WWW\Curl\Share.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\WWW\Curl\Form.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\WWW\Curl.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\WWW\Curl\Easy.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\WWW\Curl\Multi.pm (unchanged)
gcc -c  -Id:\curldev\include    -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IM
PLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2
  -DVERSION=\"4.15\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"4.15\"  "-ID:\perl\perl\lib\CORE"   Curl.
c
Curl.xs: In function 'XS_WWW__Curl__Easy_init':
D:\perl\perl\lib\CORE/XSUB.h:526:20: error: 'PerlSIO_fread' undeclared (first us e in this function)
D:\perl\perl\lib\CORE/XSUB.h:526:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Curl.xs:620: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'Curl.o'
```

The questions is: what is causing this error?
May be it has something to do with the Warning lines in the messages after running Makefile.PL, but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound crazy but, I was able to get over this by commenting out the undeclared variables in the corresponding file. It also complains about PerlISO_fwrite or something similar. you will have to comment that as well

Answer (score 0):

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?ShowHeaders=1;id=62609

Adding this to the curl.xs file fixes it:

```
#include "XSUB.h"

/* add new code here */
#ifdef fread
#undef fread
#endif
#ifdef fwrite
#undef fwrite
#endif

/* end new code */ 

#include <curl/curl.h>
```